# Robot Framework/Selenium - Having trouble with dropdown lists

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I know its a common question, but bear with me, as I really have no idea how to even solve this.

I need my robotframework code to click on a dropdown list.

So the html code for the desired list on the page I am testing is as follows:

```html
<div class="col-sm-new">
  <div class="grid-item">
    <label class="picker-option">
      <input type="radio" id="B & C" name="industry_type" value="B & C">
      <div class="item grey-bg">
        <div class="header-arrow itemname">B & C
        </div>
        <span class="itemdesc"></span>
      </div></label>
```

I really have no clue what locator I should be using. I tried

```
Click Element id=B & C
```

Locator not found

```
Select from List by Index id=B & C
```

Also throws a locator not found error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first approach could work but first you should open the drop-down menu, because before that the list item is not visible or might not even exists.

```
Click Element    #locator of the drop-down button/list
Click Element    id=B & C
```

Your second approach is not working because the [`Select from List by Index`](http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Select%20From%20List%20By%20Index) keyword expects two parameters.

> Selects options from selection list `locator` by `indexes`.
>
> Indexes of list options start from 0.

You did not pass the `locator` of the list, which can be an xPath expression or CSS selector and you did not pass a valid index neither. Instead you have passed the locator of the list item.

In both cases you need the locator of the list itself first, and then you can select a list item with one of the keywords below.

1. [Select From List By Label](http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Select%20From%20List%20By%20Label) to match by text. (`<div class="header-arrow itemname">B & C
       </div>`)

   ```
   Select From List By Label    id:listId    B & C
   ```
2. [Select From List By Value](http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Select%20From%20List%20By%20Value) to match by value. (`<input type="radio" id="B & C" name="industry_type" value="B & C">`)

   ```
   Select From List By Value    id:listId    B & C
   ```

---

But all of this will work only if your list has `<list>` tag and the list items have `<select>` tags. Based on the [library source code](https://github.com/robotframework/SeleniumLibrary/blob/master/src/SeleniumLibrary/keywords/selectelement.py).

```python
def _get_select_list(self, locator):
    el = self.find_element(locator, tag='list')
    return Select(el)
```

For example with a drop-down list, with simple list-item elements: `<li>`, the following error would occur:

> Message: Select only works on `<select>` elements, not on `<li>`

---

This would lead back to a custom solution instead of the rarely usable `Select From List ...` keywords. Here is an example you can try here on SQA.

```python
*** Settings ***
Library     SeleniumLibrary

*** Variables ***
${SE HELP LOCATOR}    //a[@class='-link js-help-button']

Select Element From Se Help Dropdown
    [Arguments]     ${item label}
    # Open drop-down
    Click Element   ${SE HELP LOCATOR}
    # Click on item to select
    Click Element   //li/a[contains(text(),'${item label}')]
    # Optionally close the drop-down here if needed
    # Click Element   ${dropdown locator}

*** Test Cases ***
Select From List Example
    [Tags]     SQA
    [Setup]    Open Browser    https://sqa.stackexchange.com/    Firefox
    Maximize Browser Window
    Set Selenium Speed      0.1

    Select Element From Se Help Dropdown    Help Center

    Location Should Be    https://sqa.stackexchange.com/help

    [Teardown]    Close Browser
```

Based on this you should be able to create your own keyword for your own drop-down.

Answer (score 0):

Click Element   //li/a[contains(text(),'${item label}')]

This worked out. Creating a keyword and using this method will solve your issue